# gradle adds jar to classpath even though it has `implementation` dependnecy

Tags: java, gradle

I'm converting a large project from Maven to Gradle. All of the projects, except for one, use `java-library` plugin.

One of the projects, let's call it `build-info-impl` creates a `.jar`. file with `build.properties` file with the current date, commit hash and other properties. The date, of course, changes every time a build occurs so that task is marked with `outputs.upToDateWhen { false }`.

Other projects depends on that `build-info-impl` using `implementation` dependency like so

`dependencies {
    implementation project(':mqm-server-root:mqm-infra-common:mqm-build-info')
}`

**The problem**

When I build the projects the `test` task of all sub-projects always run. When I add `--info` I see the following output:

`Executing task ':server-root:pom:platform-services:platform-services-impl:test' (up-to-date check took 0.017 secs) due to:
  Input property 'classpath' file C:\Users\user\Documents\dev\project\gradle\Server\infra-common\build-info-impl\build\libs\build-info-impl-1.24.9-SNAPSHOT.jar has changed.`

As far as I understand this means that the `.jar` file did get into the classpath even though the [Java-Library plugin documentation clearly state](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#useJavaLibraryPlugin):

> Dependencies found in the implementation configuration will, on the
>   other hand, not be exposed to consumers, and therefore not leak into
>   the consumers' compile classpath

How can I debug why that `.jar` file ends on the classpath?

Comment: You're not compiling. You're testing. So the classpath used here is not the compile classpath, but the test runtime classpath. How would tests even run if you run them without any implementation of your library?

Comment: The point of that file is to record information about the build, it's not really implement anything. At runtime the application uses `build.properties` file to be able to tell which commit hash the app was built from.

Comment: So, how, at runtime, would the application be able to read the build.properties file if the jar containing it is not in the classpath?

Comment: That is a good question, it seems this was a wrong dependency we carry from the maven project we are converting to Gradle. So, gradle was right :)